# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewHelper.class

Tags: android, android-multidex

I've been working on an application for a few weeks, today I added a map activity which Ie already wrote. I had to enable multidex in my project because total of methods in my project are more than 64k. 
After all I got this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':waterManagement:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewHelper.class
```

Actually I had this jar lib in one of my libraries, I tried to delete it and use another methods but I still have this error.

 I don't know, how is it possible?
I don't have this jar file in my project anymore. I closed app, deleted .idle and *.imi file and opened it again, but I faced this problem again. I read a lot of stack to solve it, Actually I used this method in my gradle but nothing changed

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
}
```

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find, wich library on your gradle file is using nineoldandroids and exclude it adding this line

```
compile ('com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'){
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
}
```